# How to compare some different value of some field in Array List with other List and return the difference in java spring?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot

Hi what i trying to achieve is to get a different value of some properties in two list which have some same properties but not all is same. i want to get the different value and return it as a value that already change. here is what i have :

i have first DTO, which is submited from frontend ShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto.java that looked like this :

```
@Data
public class ShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public String address;

    public Boolean isActive;

    public Long partnerShipmentId;
    
}
```

and here is my DTO that i got front another API, PartnerShipmentDto.java :

```
@Data
public class PartnerShipmentDto {

    public Long id;

    public String partnerShipmentCode;

    public String address;

    public String phoneNumber;

    public String region;

    public String subPartnerName;

    public String subPartnerAddress;

    public Integer olt;

    public String typeShipment;

    public Boolean allowBigVehicle;

    public Boolean isActive;
    
}
```

i want compare these two object using two properties, first field isActive and second address, if these field is different, which is changed on the remote (Other API) side, i want notice the user that the value has changed into new value, and in the future i want compare another same name properties not just these two properties (isActive and address).

i need to compare two list, first ***shipmentAddressGroupingDto*** and second ***partnerShipmentDto***.

notes : in PartnerShipmentDto .getId is refer to ShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto .getPartnerShipmentId as the referral

Here is what i do, in my service.java :

```
//here is how i got the data from front end 
        ShipmentAddressGroupingDto shipmentAddressGroupingDto = request.getObject();
        List<ShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto> shipmentAddressGroupingDtDto = shipmentAddressGroupingDto.getShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto();

// here is how i got the data from remote API
        List<PartnerShipmentDto> partnerShipmentDto = webClient.post().uri(url).body(Mono.just(partnerShipmentIds),
            PartnerShipmentDto.class).retrieve().bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PartnerShipmentDto>>() {}).block();


    for(int i=0; i < shipmentAddressGroupingDtDto.size(); i++) {
        ShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto s = shipmentAddressGroupingDtDto.get(i);
        for(int a=0; a < partnerShipmentDto.size(); a++) {
            if(s.getPartnerShipmentId().equals(partnerShipmentDto.get(a).getId())){
                Boolean isActiveResult = s.getIsActive().equals(partnerShipmentDto.get(a).getIsActive());
                Boolean addressResult = s.getAddress().equals(partnerShipmentDto.get(a).getAddress());

                if(!isActiveResult){
                    throw new ResourceAlreadyChange("Active already change");
                } else if(!addressResult) {
                    throw new ResourceAlreadyChange("Address already change");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i achieve this result without to many for loop and add if for each field? is java have some feature maybe using lambda expression or something else to achieve this? maybe using one or two dimension for loop is okay but not using if condition based in the properties, can java find some same name properties and compare it and get the value that have difference(on left or right side is okay) between them? so i don't have to add if condition for every properties that i have to compare because they already have same properties name. please help me with example

is my service.java clear enough? i will improve my question if i am not really clear

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and more clearly what you want as an outcome (right now it is not clear )

Comment: oh sorry i just updated my answer @JAsgarov can u help me upvote my question so it's not minus? just if u don't mind haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use Java streams to make it a bit more readable. Otherwise there isn't much improvement that comes to mind.

Hope this still helps tho :)

```
shipmentAddressGroupingDtDto.stream().forEach(shipmentAdressGroupingDto -> {
  partnerShipmentDto.stream().forEach(partnerShipmentDto -> {
      if(partnerShipmentDto.getId().equals(shipmentAdressGroupingDto.getId())){
          Boolean isActiveResult = s.getIsActive().equals(partnerShipmentDto.get(a).getIsActive());
          Boolean addressResult = s.getAddress().equals(partnerShipmentDto.get(a).getAddress());

          if(!isActiveResult){
             throw new ResourceAlreadyChange("Active already change");
          }else if(!addressResult){
             throw new ResourceAlreadyChange("Address already change");
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i see.. very nice POV, thank you. still wait for other solution that maybe have more simple syntax to do the comparison